# Colour picker Texture paint pie menu

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to add the colour picker in the texture paint panel to a pie menu ?

[image]

Comment: Do you already have a pie menu script working tha tyou need to add it to, or are you asking if there is a pie menu out there that does this?

Comment: No I don't have it, I read the source code for the paint panel and can't figure anything out. I need the color picker in the custom pie menu.

Comment: Not a complete answer, so I will just leave as a comment - you can use Texture Paint Plus and check out how the BrushPopup operator works, and see if you can get the code figured out in a pie menu instead. https://github.com/artistCDMJ/texture_paint_plus/blob/master/__init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels and Menus use the same methods to display properties and operators, the main difference is that a pie menu will show properties floating by themselves unless you create a [box](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.box) as a background for them.

To make your own pie menu start with the [pie menu template](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_pie_menu.py) that is included with blender.

To show a colour swatch that will pop-up a colour picker when clicked you use [`layout.prop()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) to display the colour property. To show the colour picker itself you can use [`layout.template_color_picker()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_color_picker).

An example pie menu that shows both -

[image: example pie menu for colour picking]

```
class ColourPie(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = 'Set Colours'
    bl_idname = 'OBJECT_MT_colour_pie'

    def draw(self, context):
        ts = context.tool_settings
        ups = ts.unified_paint_settings
        ptr = ups if ups.use_unified_color else ts.image_paint.brush

        pie = self.layout.menu_pie()
        row = pie.row()
        # add a colour swatch that can popup a colour picker
        row.prop(ptr, 'color')
        box = pie.box()
        #show the colour picker directly
        box.template_color_picker(ptr, 'color', value_slider=True)
```