# How to store the color of Colorpickers

Tags: python, scripting

I made a piemenu where you can select colors with a colorpicker. I would like to store the picked color in an attribute that I can access. In *File>User Preferences>Themes* it seems like it can be stored in attributes such as 'ThemeBoneColorSet.normal'. I don't know how to make such attributes myself nor how to access them to store the output.

[image]

The relevant lines of code that specify the output of the color picker (I can't find that brush, code from this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82549/colour-picker-texture-paint-pie-menu/82579)):

```
def draw(self, context):
    ts = context.tool_settings
    ups = ts.unified_paint_settings
    ptr = ups if ups.use_unified_color else ts.image_paint.brush
```

The current version of the piemenu and the script that produces it (note that you may not get the buttons as I specify them in a different addon):

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu


# spawn an edit mode selection pie (run while object is in edit mode to get a valid output)

class Carpaint(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.carpaint"
    bl_label = "Carpaint"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class FrontLights(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.frontlights"
    bl_label = "FrontLights"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}
class BackLights(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.backlights"
    bl_label = "BackLights"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class Wheels(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.wheels"
    bl_label = "Wheels"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class Rims(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.rims"
    bl_label = "Rims"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class MetalParts(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.metalparts"
    bl_label = "MetalParts"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class test(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.test"
    bl_label = "TestTest"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}


class Windows(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.windows"
    bl_label = "Windows"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class Plastic(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.plastic"
    bl_label = "Plastic"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        return {'FINISHED'}

class ColourPie(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = 'Set Colours'
    bl_idname = 'OBJECT_MT_colour_pie'

    def draw(self, context):
        ts = context.tool_settings
        ups = ts.unified_paint_settings
        ptr = ups if ups.use_unified_color else ts.image_paint.brush
        #ptr = bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color

        pie = self.layout.menu_pie()
        base = pie.row()
        col = base.column()
        row0 = col.row()
        row1 = col.row()
        row2 = col.row()
        row3 = col.row()
        row4 = col.row()
        row5 = col.row()
        row6 = col.row()
        row7 = col.row()

        row0.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row0.operator('wm.carpaint')

        row1.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row1.operator('wm.frontlights')

        row2.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row2.operator('wm.backlights')

        row3.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row3.operator('wm.windows')

        row4.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row4.operator('wm.wheels')

        row5.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row5.operator('wm.rims')

        row6.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row6.operator('wm.metalparts')

        row7.prop(ptr, 'color')
        row7.operator('wm.plastic')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColourPie)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColourPie)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="OBJECT_MT_colour_pie")
```

[image]

Comment: The example from Themes shows the values of  different color properties ((Regular outline etc).  The color is not stored in the picker it is the value of the property. Your example are all the same since  `ts0 = ts1 = ts2 = context.tool_settings`

Comment: @batFINGER  Could you tell me hove how I can store the picked color in a self-created UI element? I guess I can hack by it by storing them in the themes colors, but that's suboptimal

Comment: @sambler, may I link you, as you answered a question that 'inspired' this question

Comment: @WhatAMesh You might find [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17755/10985) helpful. Normally you store these properties just on static properties of your operator, and then draw them in the `draw` function with `layout.prop()`. But there's a second way in that answer that may also work for you.