# Draw existing panel in pie menu

Tags: interface, customization, panel, pie-menu

I seem close but can't quite figure out how to draw an existing panel, in this case "VIEW3D_PT_sculpt_context_menu" in a pie menu.

using `pie.popover("VIEW3D_PT_sculpt_context_menu")`
draws the panel but in a submenu:
[image]

I can access the menu with `bpy.types.VIEW3D_PT_sculpt_context_menu` but cannot follow with .draw() since it is already in a draw context of the pie menu.

Following [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82549/colour-picker-texture-paint-pie-menu) i can get a colour picker to draw, which seems to say it is possible (:

full pie menu in a [pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/pWSJ6bAm)